# AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, configuration

I know some of you might think that its a little bit off topic here, but am not sure whether its fault of server OR fault of my config file, so...

I made React.js project , but it needs server side rendering, So now I have to migrate from CRA to next.js . the problem: I have to upload my website on apache web server, from what I gathered from google, I need installed node.js and pm2 (latest versions), also configured apache for reverse proxy. I also created ecoystem for pm2(I guess it was necessary). it looks like this at the moment:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "nextjs-app",
    script: "npm",
    args: "run build",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "production"
    }
  }]
};
```

but when I ran pm2 start npm -- start , terminal is giving me respone like this:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/georgianar/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /usr/local/bin/npm in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
```

but when I try to see list of process, there is none, and when user tries to enter the website, site log shows that there is no service on port 3000

```
AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

and

```
(111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (localhost:3000) failed
```

so, am not sure its fault of server or its my config file causing this chaos. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the following commands exists in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "next start -p 3000"
  }
```

Use the following command

```
pm2 start yarn --name "nextjs-app" --interpreter bash -- start
```

You can print out detail process information using

```
pm2 show nextjs-app
```

Configure PM2 to Start on Server Boot, run the below command as **root**

```
pm2 startup
```

Save the pm2 process list to relaunch them after a server reboot

```
pm2 save
```